# Sort header from HTTP response before writing it to a file

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, http-headers, network-protocols

I am currently trying to implement a HTTP client using python and sockets. It is very simple and the only thing it has to do is to download a file from a webserver and put it into a file supplied by the user.

My code is working fine but I am having a problem of how to exclude the HTTP response header from the file.

The HTTP response header is only at the beginning of the file so I was thinking that I could just dump all the data into the file and then take the header out after. This is a problem though since I/O is very slow.

My next thought was that I could run some Regex on the first response I get from the server, sort away the header and then dump the rest into the file. This seems as a very clunky way to do it though.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this in a smart way?

Answer (score 1):

In the http response, the headers are separated from the body with `'\r\n\r\n'`. To get only the body, you can try this:

```
bodyBegin = httpResponse.find('\r\n\r\n') + 4
body = httpResponse[bodyBegin:]
saveToFile(body)
```